# dart: converting a bitmap image to png, Image.fromBytes complains about missing data

Tags: dart, image-conversion

i am trying to convert an obscure bitmap image format to png, the images are stored as hexadecimal grids of greyshades,

i created a Uint8List out of that data (and i checked values range from 0 - 255) that matches the desired size:

```
Uint8List uintList = Uint8List.fromList(expandedBits);
      print("prior to fromBytes  ${width}, ${height}= ${width*height} vs ${uintList.length} vs ${uintList.lengthInBytes}");
      // Create an Image from the bitmap data array
      Image image = Image.fromBytes(width: width, height: height, bytes: Uint8List.fromList(expandedBits).buffer);
```

but somehow this fails with a cryptic message:

```
prior to fromBytes  32, 32= 1024 vs 1024 vs 1024
Error reading the input file: RangeError (end): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 960..1024: 1056
```

from my understanding i want an image of 32 x 32 pt, and i supply a list of (32 x 32 = 1024) values that represent those greyshades, where does an index of 1056 comes from?

i expected an image i could export to png

Comment: It is possibly worth a try padding the buffer with an extra 32 bytes and see if that helps or generates a different error message. Some formats require lines to be a multiple of 4 bytes long but that can't explain this case since 32 = 8x4.

Comment: well i tripled the whole thing before there was enough data.... the result makes no sense though so i think i really need to understand what image expects...

Comment: 3x hints that it may be expecting RGB tuples for each pixel rather than 8 bit greyscale. My guess is that you are in sRGB colour space by default and have to explicitly tell it that your data is a greyscale image (or else set the tuples how it expects to see them. This may be relevant [Image Byte Format](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageByteFormat.html)

Comment: 1. What `Image` class are you using?  I presume from `package:image`? 2. [`Image.fromBytes`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/Image/Image.fromBytes.html) presumes that `numChannels` is 3 if not specified, but you should be specifying `numChannels: 1` since you have only a grayscale channel.